# Unwind Multiple Document Arrays Into New Documents

Tags: javascript, mongodb, aggregation-framework

Today I run into a situation I need to sync a mongoDB collection to vertica (SQL Database) where my object keys will be the columns of the table in SQL.
I use mongoDB aggregation framework, first to query, manipulate and project the wanted result document and then I sync it to vertica.

The schema I want to aggregate looks like this:

```
{
  userId: 123
  firstProperty: {
    firstArray: ['x','y','z'],
    anotherAttr: 'abc'
  },
  anotherProperty: {
    secondArray: ['a','b','c'],
    anotherAttr: 'def'
  }  
}
```

Since array values are not related with other arrays value, what I need is that each value of nested array, will be in a separate result document.
For that I use the following aggregation pipe:

```
db.collection('myCollection').aggregate([
            {
                $match: {
                    $or: [
                        {'firstProperty.firstArray.1': {$exists: true}},
                        {'secondProperty.secondArray.1': {$exists: true}}
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                $project: {
                    userId: 1,
                    firstProperty: 1,
                    secondProperty: 1
                }
            }, {
                $unwind: {path:'$firstProperty.firstAray'}
            }, {
                $unwind: {path:'$secondProperty.secondArray'},
            }, {
                $project: {
                    userId: 1,
                    firstProperty: '$firstProperty.firstArray',
                    firstPropertyAttr: '$firstProperty.anotherAttr',
                    secondProperty: '$secondProperty.secondArray',
                    seondPropertyAttr: '$secondProperty.anotherAttr'
                }
            }, {
                $out: 'another_collection'
            }
        ])
```

What I expect is the following result:

```
{
  userId: 'x1',
  firstProperty: 'x',
  firstPropertyAttr: 'a'
}
{
  userId: 'x1',
  firstProperty: 'y',
  firstPropertyAttr: 'a'
}
{
  userId: 'x1',
  firstProperty: 'z',
  firstPropertyAttr: 'a'
}
{
  userId: 'x1',
  secondProperty: 'a',
  firstPropertyAttr: 'b'
}
{
  userId: 'x1',
  secondProperty: 'b',
  firstPropertyAttr: 'b'
}
{
  userId: 'x1',
  secondProperty: 'c',
  firstPropertyAttr: 'b'
}
```

Instead I get something like that:

```
{
  userId: 'x1',
  firstProperty: 'x',
  firstPropertyAttr: 'b'
  secondProperty: 'a',
  secondPropertyAttr: 'b'
}
{
  userId: 'x1',
  firstProperty: 'y',
  firstPropertyAttr: 'b'
  secondProperty: 'b',
  secondPropertyAttr: 'b'
}
{
  userId: 'x1',
  firstProperty: 'z',
  firstPropertyAttr: 'b'
  secondProperty: 'c',
  secondPropertyAttr: 'b'
}
```

What exactly am I missing, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Your expected result contains documents with different field names. Some of them have firstProperty while others have secondProperty. Is that what you really want to achieve ?

Comment: Noting that both your expected output and current output don't actually match the data given, or correlate to the aggregation pipeline provided. But the pipeline does actually make it clear where the data "should" be coming from. Your expected output in particular looks like you lost track of the naming, but I believe I follow the general gist of "object keys as names of columns" that you were intending to present.

Comment: Well, yes. I need the final properties be named differently since they represent different sources of data arrays. But that's exactly what I do in the final projection in the pipeline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually a much "curlier" problem than you might think it is, and it all really boils down to "named keys", which are generally a real problem and your data "should" not be using "data points" in the naming of such keys.

The other obvious problem in your attempt is called a "cartesian product". This is where you [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) one array and then [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) another, which results in the items from the "first" [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) being repeated for every value present in the "second".

Addressing that second problem, the basic approach is to "combine the arrays" in order that you only [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) from a single source. This is pretty common to all remaining approaches.

As for the approaches, these differ in the MongoDB version you have available and the general practicality of application. So let's step through them:

## Remove the named keys

The most simple approach here is to simply not expect named keys in the output, and instead mark them as a `"name"` identifying their source in the final output. So all we want to do is specify each "expected" key within the construction of an initial "combined" array, and then simply [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) that for any `null` values resulting from named paths not existing in the present document.

```
db.getCollection('myCollection').aggregate([
  { "$match": {
    "$or": [
      { "firstProperty.firstArray.0": { "$exists": true } },
      { "anotherProperty.secondArray.0": { "$exists": true } }
    ]  
  }},
  { "$project": {
    "_id": 0,
    "userId": 1,
    "combined": {
      "$filter": {
        "input": [
          { 
            "name": { "$literal": "first" },
            "array": "$firstProperty.firstArray",
            "attr": "$firstProperty.anotherAttr"
          },
          {
            "name": { "$literal": "another" },
            "array": "$anotherProperty.secondArray",
            "attr": "$anotherProperty.anotherAttr"
          }
        ],
        "cond": {
          "$ne": ["$$this.array", null ]
        }
      }
    }
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$combined" },
  { "$unwind": "$combined.array" },
  { "$project": {
    "userId": 1,
    "name": "$combined.name",
    "value": "$combined.array",
    "attr": "$combined.attr"
  }}
])
```

From the data included in your question this would produce:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "userId" : 123.0,
    "name" : "first",
    "value" : "x",
    "attr" : "abc"
}

/* 2 */
{
    "userId" : 123.0,
    "name" : "first",
    "value" : "y",
    "attr" : "abc"
}

/* 3 */
{
    "userId" : 123.0,
    "name" : "first",
    "value" : "z",
    "attr" : "abc"
}

/* 4 */
{
    "userId" : 123.0,
    "name" : "another",
    "value" : "a",
    "attr" : "def"
}

/* 5 */
{
    "userId" : 123.0,
    "name" : "another",
    "value" : "b",
    "attr" : "def"
}

/* 6 */
{
    "userId" : 123.0,
    "name" : "another",
    "value" : "c",
    "attr" : "def"
}
```

## Merge Objects - Requires MongoDB 3.4.4 minimum

To actually use "named keys" we need the [`$objectToArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/) and [`$arrayToObject`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/) operators that were only available since MongoDB 3.4.4. Using these and the [`$replaceRoot`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/) pipeline stage we can simply process to your desired output without **explicitly** naming the keys to output at any stage:

```
db.getCollection('myCollection').aggregate([
  { "$match": {
    "$or": [
      { "firstProperty.firstArray.0": { "$exists": true } },
      { "anotherProperty.secondArray.0": { "$exists": true } }
    ]  
  }},
  { "$project": {
    "_id": 0,
    "userId": 1,
    "data": {
      "$reduce": {
        "input": {
          "$map": {
            "input": {
              "$filter": {
                "input": { "$objectToArray": "$$ROOT" },
                "cond": { "$not": { "$in": [ "$$this.k", ["_id", "userId"] ] } }
              }
            },
            "as": "d",
            "in": {
              "$let": {
                "vars": {
                  "inner": {
                    "$map": {
                      "input": { "$objectToArray": "$$d.v" },
                      "as": "i",
                      "in": {
                        "k": {
                          "$cond": {
                            "if": { "$ne": [{ "$indexOfCP": ["$$i.k", "Array"] }, -1] },
                            "then": "$$d.k",
                            "else": { "$concat": ["$$d.k", "Attr"] }
                          }  
                        },
                        "v": "$$i.v"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                },
                "in": {
                  "$map": {
                    "input": { 
                      "$arrayElemAt": [
                        "$$inner.v",
                        { "$indexOfArray": ["$$inner.k", "$$d.k"] } 
                      ]
                    },
                    "as": "v",
                    "in": {
                      "$arrayToObject": [[
                        { "k": "$$d.k", "v": "$$v" },
                        { 
                          "k": { "$concat": ["$$d.k", "Attr"] },
                          "v": {
                            "$arrayElemAt": [
                              "$$inner.v",
                              { "$indexOfArray": ["$$inner.k", { "$concat": ["$$d.k", "Attr"] }] }
                            ]
                          }
                        }
                      ]]
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "initialValue": [],
        "in": { "$concatArrays": [ "$$value", "$$this" ] }
      }
    }
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$data" },
  { "$replaceRoot": {
    "newRoot": {
      "$arrayToObject": {
        "$concatArrays": [
          [{ "k": "userId", "v": "$userId" }],
          { "$objectToArray": "$data" }
        ]
      } 
    }   
  }}
])
```

Which gets pretty monstrous from converting the "keys" into an array, then the "sub-keys" into an array and mapping the values from those inner arrays onto the pair of keys in output.

The key parts being [`$objectToArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/) is essentially needed to "transform" your "nested key" structures into arrays of `"k"` and `"v"` representing the "name" of the key and the "value". This gets called twice, being once for the "outer" parts of the document and excluding the "constant" fields such as `"_id"` and `"userId"` into such an array structure. Then the second call is processed on each of those "array" elements in order to make those "inner keys" a similar "array".

Matching is then done using [`$indexOfCP`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/indexOfCP/) to work out which "inner key" is the one for the value and which is the "Attr". The keys are then renamed here to the "outer" key value, which we can access because that's a `"v"` courtesy of [`$objectToArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/).

Then for the "inner value" which is an "array", we want to [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) each entry into a combined "array" which basically has the form:

```
[
  { "k": "firstProperty", "v": "x" },
  { "k": "firstPropertyAttr", "v": "abc" }
]
```

This happens for each "inner array" element, for which [`$arrayToObject`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/) reverses the process and turns each `"k"` and `"v"` into "key" and "value" of an object respectively.

Since the output is still an "array of arrays" of the "inner keys" at this point, the [`$reduce`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/) wraps that output and applies [`$concatArrays`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concatArrays/) while processing each element in order to "join" into a single array for `"data"`.

All that remains is to simply [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) the array produced from each source document, and then apply [`$replaceRoot`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/), which is the part that actually allows "different key names" at the "root" of each document output.

The "merging" here is done by supplying an array of object of the same `"k"` and `"v"` construction notated for `"userId"`, and "concatentating" that with the [`$objectToArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/) transform of the `"data"`. Of course this "new array" is then converted to an object via [`$arrayToObject`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/) one final time, which forms the "object" argument to `"newRoot"` as an expression.

You do something like that when there is a large number of "named keys" that you can't really name explicitly. And it actually gives you the result you want:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "userId" : 123.0,
    "firstProperty" : "x",
    "firstPropertyAttr" : "abc"
}

/* 2 */
{
    "userId" : 123.0,
    "firstProperty" : "y",
    "firstPropertyAttr" : "abc"
}

/* 3 */
{
    "userId" : 123.0,
    "firstProperty" : "z",
    "firstPropertyAttr" : "abc"
}

/* 4 */
{
    "userId" : 123.0,
    "anotherProperty" : "a",
    "anotherPropertyAttr" : "def"
}

/* 5 */
{
    "userId" : 123.0,
    "anotherProperty" : "b",
    "anotherPropertyAttr" : "def"
}

/* 6 */
{
    "userId" : 123.0,
    "anotherProperty" : "c",
    "anotherPropertyAttr" : "def"
}
```

## Named Keys without MongoDB 3.4.4 or Greater

Without the operator support as shown in the above listing, it's simply not possible for the aggregation framework to output documents with different key names.

So though it's not possible to instruct the "server" to do this via `$out`, you can of course simply iterate the cursor and write a new collection

```
var ops = [];

db.getCollection('myCollection').find().forEach( d => {
  ops = ops.concat(Object.keys(d).filter(k => ['_id','userId'].indexOf(k) === -1 )
    .map(k => 
      d[k][Object.keys(d[k]).find(ki => /Array$/.test(ki))]
        .map(v => ({
          [k]: v,
          [`${k}Attr`]: d[k][Object.keys(d[k]).find(ki => /Attr$/.test(ki))]
      }))
    )
    .reduce((acc,curr) => acc.concat(curr),[])
    .map( o => Object.assign({ userId: d.userId },o) )
  );

  if (ops.length >= 1000) {
    db.getCollection("another_collection").insertMany(ops);
    ops = [];
  }

})

if ( ops.length > 0 ) {
  db.getCollection("another_collection").insertMany(ops);
  ops = [];
}
```

Same sort of thing as is being done in the earlier aggregation, but just "externally". It essentially produces and array of documents for each document matching the "inner" arrays, like so:

```
[ 
    {
        "userId" : 123.0,
        "firstProperty" : "x",
        "firstPropertyAttr" : "abc"
    }, 
    {
        "userId" : 123.0,
        "firstProperty" : "y",
        "firstPropertyAttr" : "abc"
    }, 
    {
        "userId" : 123.0,
        "firstProperty" : "z",
        "firstPropertyAttr" : "abc"
    }, 
    {
        "userId" : 123.0,
        "anotherProperty" : "a",
        "anotherPropertyAttr" : "def"
    }, 
    {
        "userId" : 123.0,
        "anotherProperty" : "b",
        "anotherPropertyAttr" : "def"
    }, 
    {
        "userId" : 123.0,
        "anotherProperty" : "c",
        "anotherPropertyAttr" : "def"
    }
]
```

These get "cached" into a big array, which when that reaches a length of 1000 or more is finally written to the new collection via [`.insertMany()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insertMany/). Of course that requires "back and forth" communication with the server, but it does get the job done in the most efficient way possible if you don't have the features available for the previous aggregation.

## Conclusion

The overall point here is that unless you actually have a MongoDB that supports it, then you are not going to get documents with "different key names" in the output, solely from the aggregation pipeline.

So when you do not have that support, you either go with the first option and then use [`$out`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/) discarding having named keys. Or you do the final approach and simply manipulate the cursor results and write back to the new collection.

Comment: The first solution you've suggested ("Remove the named keys") perfectly does what I need.
My data looks little bit different in reality, but the example I gave simplifies it.
Thanks a lot.